# Would it make sense to backpack with an 8 lb tent at Philmont Scout Ranch?

Tags: backpacking, united-states, tents

I am going to [Philmont Scout Ranch](http://www.philmontscoutranch.org/About.aspx) in the Rocky Mountains in New Mexico, USA, this August. I am planning on using the Eureka Timberline 4 tent, which weighs about 8 pounds. I am doing a 7 day trek and would like to know if this would make sense.

Comment: If you know people who used to do treks, you might be able to find a light weight tent that you can borrow or buy for a sweet small price. If you know people who do treks they might be able to help you find a cheap (second hand) tent or you might be able to borrow an older one. (Do not expect to borrow their good one but it does happen.)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read through some of the posts at https://backpackinglight.com/forums/forum/scouting/philmont/

Comment: Go for it.  It will build character.  Get a couple people to share.

Comment: Are you strong?

Comment: Sounds like great exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether an 8 lb tent makes sense depends on a couple of things,

- If you are the only one using it then no, if you can split the weight between 4 people probably yes.
- Whether for your budget you can get a lighter tent, the lighter you go the more expensive it will be, at some point it won't be worth it on your budget.

Looking at that tent I would suggest getting something lighter for backpacking with.

Answer (score 4):

No, that is way too heavy (and large for 2 Scouts). You would be better off just using what Philmont offers, which are about 6 pounds the last I knew. Call and verify availability.

You would be even better getting a lighter one if you can afford it, but they get more expensive the lighter you go. I like the Six Moon Designs Lunar Duo for backpacking, but it's $325. Their outfitter version is an extra pound but cost about half that (I have 2 of those for Scouts to use). However, they are currently out of stock. Those also require the use of trekking poles (i.e., not freestanding).